# Absolue position nightmare - can't even center main content with whole-body bg

Tags: css, positioning

Ten minutes in and already I'm in over my head for some reason, and any help is much appreciated. I have a layout I'm trying to code, seen [here](http://personal.justgooddesign.net/dailydose/DailyDose.jpg). Basically I want the background image (the coffee beans) to stay fixed as you scroll down the page. However, the main content does not want to stay centered, and the bg image does not want to stay fixed. No matter what I do, the main body either winds up aligning to the left instead of center, or the bg image gets way screwed up. Anyone that can point me in the right direction is a hero! The page so far can be seen [here](http://personal.justgooddesign.net/dailydose/index.html).

```
    html, body {
background-color: #e0dac8;
}
#content {
background-image: url(IMG/bg_head.jpg);
background-color: #e0dac8;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
position: absolute;
}
#wrapper {
margin: auto;
height: auto;
width: auto;
```

}

Comment: Justin, can you post the pertinent code here in the question?  Otherwise this question won't be useful to anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it that you want? http://jsfiddle.net/LRxpA/embedded/result/

I deleted postion absolute and centered #content with "margin: 0 auto;", then fixed background with "background-attachment: fixed;".

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/LRxpA/

Answer (score 1):

Don't use absolute positioning for this.

Just add margins:

```
#content {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: How should I go about keeping the coffee image fixed at the top then while the rest of the content scrolls?

Answer (score 1):

```
#content {  margin:0 auto;}
```

will do the trick.

[Something I tried](http://jsfiddle.net/maxisam/nPf6u/18/)

Comment: Actually you question is more than this. I think you need to change the layout.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Tried the new code, but did not change anything.

Comment: Check out the link i just added